# Intel chipset drivers confusion

Tags: drivers, chipset

I'm installing Windows on an Asus P5B-E (Intel chipset) and wish to use the most recent drivers available, but I'm having trouble figuring out which chipset download I want.

The original motherboard CD lists the chipset driver as the 'Intel Chipset Inf Update Program', and on the Asus chipset download page for this mobo they have:

```
Intel(R) Chipset Software Installation Utility V9.1.1.1019 for Windows 32/64bit XP & 32/64bit Vista & 32/64bit Windows 7.(WHQL)
Intel(R) Chipset Software Installation Utility V8.3.0.1013 for Windows 2000/XP & 64bit XP & 32/64bit Vista(WHQL).
Intel Chipset Inf Update Program v8.0.1.1002 for Windows 2000/XP(WHQL)/2003 & 64bit XP(WHQL)/2003.
Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager Driver v6.0.0.1022 for Windows 2000/XP/2003 & 64bit XP/2003(WHQL).
Intel\MakeDisk -Make Intel ICH8 RAID Driver Disk for Windows 2000/XP/2003 & 64bit XP/2003.
```

So my question, is the 'Software Installation Utility' a new version of the 'Inf Update Program', or a completely different app? I assumed at first it must be an upgrade, but the inclusion of the RAID and storage manager downloads has made me think perhaps they are different programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want the first one in the list as far as I can tell.  Both item 1 and 2 seem to be the same thing just different versions and I would assume the newest version to be the best one to use unless I had some reason to NOT believe that.  Item 3 on the list seems to be the original utility that came with your MB on that disk but, it does not seem appropriate for Windows Vista or 7.  Item 4 is simply a SATA/RAID driver.  The last item seems to the make disk utility you would need in case you cannot install the operating system without adding the 3rd party SATA drivers.  Unless you slipstream those in, the only way I know of to add them is via a floppy disk and many have simply skipped those thinking they'd never need them.  In case you are not sure what I am talking about, it would be the spot on say, XP where during the install loader it asks you to hit F6 to load 3rd party RAID drivers"

Comment: OH!... You would probably have to use Item 2 if you are using Windows 2000 (I thought the first one had 2000 included but does not appear too... might work, might not)

Comment: fair enough, thanks for having look much appreciated

Comment: I almost never use anything other than an ASUS board in my builds and I work on a helpdesk too.  Might as well put some of it to use helpin' out :)